# How can I put the names of data frames, within a list, to every corresponding row

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames and they all have names. I want to create a column that will have rows with their corresponding names so it appears like this

```
$data1
 column1 column2 name
1 1       2       data1
2 3       4       data1
3 5       6       data1

$data2
 column1 column2 name
1 1       2       data2
2 3       4       data2
3 5       6       data2
```

I managed to do it with :

```
for( i in seq_along(newList)){

  newList[[i]]$name<- rep(names(newList[i]),nrow(newList[[i]]))

}
```

but I am sure there is a more intelligent way in R

Comment: If `list_df` is list of dataframes. `Map(cbind, list_df, name = names(list_df))`

Comment: I tried what you wrote to me, but I get : Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1